# verilog with out control variables cnt

Tags: counter

> > module count(clk,rst,cnt);
>
> want to wrire the verilog code  which counts upto 7 and then down to
> 0 and repeats forever as follows. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,4,3,2,1
>
> endmodule

Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Repeat state 4 for two times while counting down:

```
module count(
    input clk, 
    input rst, 
    output cnt
);

    reg [2:0] counter;
    assign cnt = counter;

    // Count up if flag is 1'b0, count down if flag is 1'b1
    wire flag;
    assign flag = (counter == 3'b1) ? 1'b1 : (counter == 3'b0) ? 1'b0;

    // Repeat counter once if special_flag is 2'b01
    reg [1:0] special_flag;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (flag == 1'b0)
        begin
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
        else if (counter == 3'b100 && special_flag == 2'b01)
        begin
            // Do not decrease counter, reset special_flag back to 2'b0
            special_flag = 2'b0;
        end else
        begin
            counter = counter - 1;
        end

        // Set special_flag to be 2'b01 when counter is 3'b1
        if (counter == 3'b1)
        begin
            special_flag = 2'b01;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module count(
    input clk, 
    input rst, 
    output cnt
);

    reg [2:0] counter;
    assign cnt = counter;

    // Count up if flag is 1'b0, count down if flag is 1'b1
    wire flag;
    assign flag = (counter == 3'b1) ? 1'b1 : (counter == 3'b0) ? 1'b0;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (flag == 1'b0)
        begin
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
        if (flag == 1'b1)
        begin
            counter = counter - 1;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: thank you here i want to repeat the states 4 for two times. how I can achieve using this one